# Can't connect to wifi with BCM43142

Tags: wireless, broadcom

Lubuntu is the only system on the computer, I have tried for a few weeks to fix this issue but to no avail. Here is the [wireless info script output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gwb5bjmQWq/)

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 04 Oct 2018 07:40 EDT -0400

Booted last: 04 Oct 2018 00:00 EDT -0400

Script from: 10 Jan 2018 20:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.15.0-34-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 15:21:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

Lubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [1028:0564]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:58bf Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6447104  0
dell_laptop            20480  0
cfg80211              651264  1 wl
dell_wmi               16384  0
dell_smbios            16384  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,dell_smbios_smm
compat                 16384  1 cfg80211
dell_wmi_descriptor    16384  1 dell_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
wmi                    24576  3 dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_wmi_descriptor
video                  45056  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback  brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0:  mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether  brd 
    inet 192.168.1.69/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft 84907sec preferred_lft 84907sec
    inet6 fe80::7ca1:87ad:2097:59fa/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.254 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.69 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search lan

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       540     1  0 07:14 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       e950e564-f418-385e-bf25-a9677f55feea
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.69/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.254
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.254, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.254
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          lan
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        time_offset = 0
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        expiry = 1538738167
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       next_server = 192.168.1.254
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.69
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       host_name = ciara-Inspiron-5720
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       routers = 192.168.1.254
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       domain_name = lan
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.254
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.254
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::7ca1:87ad:2097:59fa/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   e950e564-f418-385e-bf25-a9677f55feea | Wired connection 1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/plusnet]] (600 root)
[connection] id=plusnet | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=PLUSNET-RTKZ
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp2s0    no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     60D2D7E603B418654C8C9AA
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           wl
vermagic:       4.15.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic/updates/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
version:        iwlwifi-stack-public:master:7276:8a669024
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     E44E0187B00EA3749FD374F
depends:        compat
retpoline:      Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist r8169

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-dkms.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist b44
blacklist bcma
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist ssb

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/libpisock9.conf]
blacklist visor

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf]
options rtl8723de ant_sel=2

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   25.109705] name 'brcm_monitor0'
[   25.109777]  wl_free+0xcb/0x280 [wl]
[   25.109855]  wl_pci_probe+0x648/0xf75 [wl]
[   25.109900]  wl_module_init+0x89/0x8b [wl]
[   37.378321] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[   37.677903] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[   37.678011] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[  118.892086] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[  118.892100] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp2s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Any help would be massively appreciated. I'm not a techie, so it is probably something really simple that I'm missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: What is your kernel now, results from terminal for `uname -a; modinfo cfg80211`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have no **kernel driver in use** for the card. It shows that there are 2 kernel modules, and one of them is blacklisted (which is fine):

```
##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries 
BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
Kernel modules: bcma, wl   <<------------------

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
Subsystem: Dell RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [1028:0564]
Kernel driver in use: r8169


[/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-dkms.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist b44
blacklist bcma     <<---------------
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist ssb
```

1.) First update apt-get:

```
apt-get update
```

2.) Then update Linux Headers (this code will determine "your" systems necessary headers) and install Broadcom DKMS:

```
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

3.) Remove any possible active drivers for the Broadcom WiFi adapter:

```
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
```

4.) Activate the wl driver for the Broadcom WiFi adapter:

```
modprobe wl
```

5.) Always best to reboot your system after things like this:

```
reboot
```

This will give you **FULL** functionality of this WiFi adapter. You will be able to connect to **5GHz networks**, even put your adapter in **monitor mode**, if you were so inclined.

It is possible that simply just using `modprobe wl` would suffice for you, since it appears that you have the kernel module installed, just not in use. I guess you could try that first, and if not, follow full instructions. Hope this helps. \

Also, this will keep you using a **Broadcom Driver**, not Realtek.
See https://wiki.debian.org/wl for more info on Broadcom wl driver.